# How to configure Finder on OS/X yosemite to only search files on local hard disk

Tags: finder, osx-yosemite

I would like to configure Finder to only search the local hard disk by default.  No Internet or Mail or anything else. Is there a way to configure Finder in that manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's all configurable in `System Preferences > Spotlight`. Uncheck any and all boxes of items you wouldn't like searched. If you have external hard drives or just folders you don't want to see returned, go to `Privacy` and add them to the list.

[image]

Comment: I had seen this already and had already removed "Internet" and "Bing Search".  However I had overlooked the "Mail" one. Anyways yours is the correct answer.